# I am receiving "Invalid constant value" when trying to add a styling theme to title in BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: flutter

I am adding a theme to the title in the BottomNavigationBarItem and i am receiving the error "Invalid constant value".

I know it isn't the type of themeing i am using because i was able to break up my theme method and use the individual constants in the next BottomNavigationBarItem.  Hmmm i was going to post a picture showing exactly what i mean here but i guess i cant yet.

this is the code that is telling me i have Invalid constant values

```dart
BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CustomIcons.wrestlingring2),
            title: Text('Event', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button),
          ),
```

this code is where i added the const values directly to the style from my buttonTheme method in my styling page

```dart
BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CustomIcons.wrestling),
            title: Text('Match Details', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: montserratFont, fontSize: smallTextSize, color: textColorLight)),
          ),
```

this is the constant values and buttonTheme from the styling page

```dart
const smallTextSize = 14.0;
const Color buttonTextColour = Color(0xffdc0000);
const String montserratFont = 'Montserrat';

const buttonTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: montserratFont,
  fontSize: buttonTextSize,
  color: textColorLight,
);
```

I noticed in the flutter code the BottomNavigationBarItem is a const and thought this might be the issue

```dart
const BottomNavigationBarItem({
    @required this.icon,
    this.title,
    Widget activeIcon,
    this.backgroundColor,
  }) : activeIcon = activeIcon ?? icon,
       assert(icon != null);
```

but then i noticed so is the RaisedButton but it is not effected by me adding a theme to it.

```dart
const RaisedButton({
    Key key,
    @required VoidCallback onPressed,
    ValueChanged<bool> onHighlightChanged,
    ButtonTextTheme textTheme,
```

If there is another way to use theme with the title in the NavigationBarItem i would appreciate it if someone could point it out.  I would rather not have to theme the entire ButtomNavigationBar.